# Why don't getElementById() work inside the owl-carousel?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

full code is here:  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzf4523y/7/)

I define a standard owl-carousel slide like this:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4 id="test">1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});

window.setCounter = function(){
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "test";
  console.log('test');
};
```

it works.

now I want to change the text in the `test` id when the document loads.

So I call the function in HTML document.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       setCounter();
});
</script>
```

in this code, owl-carousel works; console.log works but getElementById doesn't work. how can I fix it?

I mean why the text in `<h4 id="test">1</h4>` not change after call `setCounter()`?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you asked it to. If you look at the output, the carousel items are centered - which means the one you changed is out of view (way off to the left off screen), and it has been changed. Align the carousel items left and you'll see the change.

Comment: Also, since owl is cloning the nodes, the id is being duplicated - which is a no-no.

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes. if I false loop it works. but I want a loop so the solution is using a unique class instead of id...Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The option to create unique IDs or classes doesn't seem to exist, but it doesn't matter. You can solve it as done below.

HTML:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4 class="test">1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
</div>
```

You can get the collection of created elements. Index 0 is the first element, 1 the second, etc. and set the innerHTML accordingly:

```
window.setCounter = function(){
  var textLines = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
  textLines[0].innerHTML = "test";
  textLines[1].innerHTML = "test2";
  textLines[2].innerHTML = "test3";
  // etc...
};
```